# Create a file with jquery or make a ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a website. Inside this Site is the content of another website - for example with this content

```
<html>
...
<body>

<div id="1"></div>
<div id="content">

  <html><head></head><bod>another website content</body></html>

</div>
</body>
```

Now I want to create a file (example.html) with the content of the div "id=content"

How I can do that?

If its possible to do that with jquery, or should a do a kind of ajax call, with send the content to a PHP file and do in PHP the work?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: If the "another website" is on a different server, you'll get CORS issues - best to get the other site's html server side.  You can use jquery `$.load` to specify a selector or load it, parse it and then use a selector.

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. For what reason do you want to create a HTML file on the fly and upload it to your server? A better idea would be to store the data required for the page in a database, and build the HTML dynamically from a template when required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a file using js since it's a client-side language, so you must go with the second option, you could make an ajax request to your server-side script that will take the content and create the file, something like :

**JS :**

```
 $.post('my_php_script.php', {content: $('#content').html()});
```

**PHP :**

```
<?php 
    $content = $_POST['content'];
    $fp = fopen($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/example.html","wb");
    fwrite($fp, $content);
    fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: if i trie to use your suggested code, i have the problem that my html code will be convert to text for exmaple <!-- 123 --> , what i do wrong?